# Database design for user-item relationships

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm making a website to sell widgets. I have a table for widgets, each of which have a few attributes (widget name, style, etc). I also have a table for users. Widgets have unique IDs, and users also have unique IDs associated with them.

My users want to start "adding" widgets to their account. Each widget can be added to an infinite amount of users. So my question is should I make a table, lets call it User_Widget, that relates UserIDs to WidgetIDs?

Another method I was thinking of is to have a column in the User table with comma separated values (WidgetID1xQuantity, WidgetID2xQuantity, etc). If I standardize this format, I can use php to parse this and implode these into an array, which can then be cross-referenced to pull info from Widget table.

Which one is faster/better practice? If I use the User_Widget method what happens if more than one user adds the same widget? Will I just have two entries? Does this not add extra overhead?

Widget | User
wid1   | user1
wid1   | user2

Would searching through these (using JOIN, etc) be slower than the other method?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Daniel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend new table with relations
It will works faster

Comment: This is correct. Do not use comma separated values. Future developers will hunt you down and poke you in the eye. For instance, there is no straight way of searching for a value between two comma separated fields. I had to deal with this issue before, and had to create a stored procedure to copy the values in a temporary table for each and every query.

Comment: It also means you can run SQL queries that relate the users and tables separately from the php code (e.g. reporting, debugging). With a CSV field it would get way to complicated and slow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I read up on many-to-many relationships and this was definitely the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a new relation in a specific table.

Apart from the other drawbacks in the previous comments, remember that:

1) Assuming that the widget has some information linked to it, you still need to access the DB to get the widget data, so you are not actually saving much (and as others pointed out, parsing the CSV is cumbersome)
2) Forget doing stuff like "please list alla users having X but not Y and Z in their widget collection" - or at the very least forget doing it efficiently.
3) Same for "Select all users that have the same widgets owned by User Z"
4) What if you need to massively replace widget X with Widget Y? Or give everyone who has W a free Z?

There are plenty of scenarios where the dedicated table gives you easily described SQL queries, efficiency, compactness. And little (or no) cases where the CSV field "wins".